# Steps to the greybeards

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I looked at a chat where people said there were about 730ish steps along the way, but I was wondering if they counted the steps in each row as one or counted all individual steps, because in some cases there won't be one step per stair, there can be 2-4 steps where the one whole stair is. Can anyone clarify how many steps there are as every single stone slab on it's own as a step?

Answer (score 0):

I read this just recently actually, quote from the UESP:

> Although the path up is said to be 7,000 steps long, there are only 732 visible. The Creation Kit indicates that there are 1,828 step objects, though many of these are adjacent to each other so can only be counted as one step.

So there are 732 steps as we humans would see them. However, as you said, there are many more individual step blocks situated adjacent to each other.

http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Throat_of_the_World